# Angular problem with multiple Selects values. Label of one Select changes after changing another

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, select, ngmodel

I am wondering if someone can help me with my problem. I have a few selects generated in a loop. Every select has its own ngModel. I have an array smsVar and every element in array is ngModel to specific select. E.g. for 1st select it is smsVar[0] etc.

When changing select option next selects label changes. I am logging values of an array to a console and they are correct. Only labels change. In addition it only happens when select is not touched/dirty. When I select value of 2nd select and then I select value od 1st select it is not affecting the 2nd one.
Code for generating selects:

```
 <div class="sms-variable" *ngFor="let option of smsVar, index as i">
              <div style="flex: 10;">
                <span (click)="moveVarUp(i)" class="arrow"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></span>
                <span (click)="moveVarDown(i)" class="arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
              </div>
              <div style="flex: 10">#{{i + 1}}#</div>
              <div style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end; flex: 80">
                <div class="col-md-6" style="flex-direction: row;">
                  <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="smsVar[i]" style="display: inline-block" (ngModelChange)="varChanged($event)">
                    <option *ngFor="let header of smsVariableLabels" [attr.value]="header.value">{{ 'SMS_VARIABLES_LABEL_' + header.value | translate}}</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

That code generates sth like this:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CPng.png)

When I change first select value it affects second select: [changed select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFcFN.png)

Console logs actual values of smsVar array and it is ok: ["FIRSTNAME", "DEFAULT", "DEFAULT"]

Comment: you can use `[(ngModel)]="option"`, but I think that your problem is in your function varChanged($event) - I imagine you can pass also the "index" "i" `((ngModelChange)="varChanged($event,i)`. NOTE: If the only you need is change the value of the smsVar[i] it's unnecesary because you already has the "[(ngModel)]"

Comment: my varChanged function is used only to console.log smsVar and finding if any select has 'PHONENUMBER' value. It's not it :/

Comment: I didn't see, but is a `;` in the *ngFor like say the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description): `*ngFor="let option of smsVar; index as i"` or `*ngFor="let option of smsVar; let i=index"`. You can use also [value] -or [ngValue] **not** [attr.value]. I don't see another error in the code